# ERROR ITMS-90045: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

This error popped up when I tried to upload my .ipa to the App Store. I tried to Clean the project in Xamarin and regenerate all the provision files but still, doesn't solve the issues.

[image]

Comment: Are you using any third-party bound libraries in your application? *Usually* this is seen when you have multiple `Info.plist` files in your bundle.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, I use some other libraries. How can I fix it? Where can I view the bundle? I'm new to Xamarin.

Comment: An IPA is just a zip file, so unzip your created app and search its files to see if there are multiple Info.plist files to determine if this is the problem...

Comment: @SushiHangover it has 2 of this line <key>LaunchScreen.storyboardc/Info.plist</key>. So can I delete it directly from the unzipped file ?

Comment: Does your original Info.plist have multiple `<key>LaunchScreen.storyboardc/Info.plist</key>` entires? You need to find the source of the extra entry so the bundle is signed properly.

Comment: how did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

change Entitlements.plist to this

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

This fix worked for me using Visual Studio for Mac v7.7 Your provisioning profile and signing identity must be set up on IDE correctly:

1. Go to `Project Options` -> `iOS Bundle Signing`.
2. Choose `Release` on `Configuration` spinner. `iPhone` for `Platform` spinner too.
3. Change `Info.plist` option by `Entitlements.plist` on `Custom Entitlements` field.

Build iPA.